# Bash scripting data parsing of LDAP dump

Tags: bash

I'm attempting to create a Bash script to pull out four fields from my LDAP hostinfo dump, and only those containing a "Wireless MacAddress" string/field.  I've attempted to create regex strings to parse out those four fields I wanted, but still can't seem to piece that together with the "only those that have the "Wireless MacAddress" field by each host.

Sample datasets: "Sorry for the CODE format, it wouldn't let me submit without indenting it as code"

```
host.name.TLD (IP.IP.IP.IP) uniq=123456
CPU = PC    OS = Linux
Location = BUILDING/NUMBER (CITY, STATEABRV (XX))
Admin = USER F. NAME (LOGINNAME)
User = USER F. NAME (LOGINNAME)
ANCILLARY FIELD = <RANDOM>
ANCILLARY FIELD = <RANDOM>
DeviceClass = desktop
Registered MacAddress = bb:cc:dd:ee:ff:aa
(IPv6 = 2019:2019:2019:2019:2019:2019)

host.name.TLD (IP.IP.IP.IP) uniq=345612
CPU = PC    OS = Linux
Location = BUILDING/NUMBER (CITY, STATEABRV (XX))
Admin = USER F. NAME (LOGINNAME)
User = USER F. NAME (LOGINNAME)
ANCILLARY FIELD = <RANDOM>
ANCILLARY FIELD = <RANDOM>
DeviceClass = desktop
Registered MacAddress = aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
Wireless MacAddress = dd:ee:ff:aa:bb:cc
(IPv6 = 2019:2019:2019:2019:2019:2019)

host.name.TLD (IP.IP.IP.IP) uniq=234561
CPU = PC    OS = Linux
Location = BUILDING/NUMBER (CITY, STATEABRV (XX))
Admin = USER F. NAME (LOGINNAME)
User = USER F. NAME (LOGINNAME)
ANCILLARY FIELD = <RANDOM>
ANCILLARY FIELD = <RANDOM>
DeviceClass = desktop
Registered MacAddress = ee:ff:aa:bb:cc:dd
(IPv6 = 2019:2019:2019:2019:2019:2019)
```

regex strings I've attempted to use to parse the four fields I need:

```
$hostname=^.*.TLD  to find the HOST.NAME.TLD
$ip=(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
$admin="Couldn't come up with anything here"
$user="Couldn't come up with anything here"
$wireless_macaddr=([0-9a-fA-F]{2}:??){5}([0-9a-fA-F]{2})
```

While each of these regex strings can find the data it's meant to look for, minus the admin and user I can't seem to create regex's for, I don't know how to only grab the specified fields I need ONLY when there is a "Wireless MacAddress."

```
host.name.TLD (IP.IP.IP.IP)
Admin = USER F. NAME (LOGINNAME)
User = USER F. NAME (LOGINNAME)
Wireless MacAddress = dd:ee:ff:aa:bb:cc
```

It's been a really long since I touched bash.  I only mention using bash because it's the only scripting language I have experience with, and not much at that.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This would be the desired output:

host.name.TLD (IP.IP.IP.IP)
Admin = USER F. NAME (LOGINNAME)
User = USER F. NAME (LOGINNAME)
Wireless MacAddress = dd:ee:ff:aa:bb:cc

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look!

Comment: `code` format is always better for code/data/cfg/errMsgs(exact text please) ;-). Good luck.

Comment: You're not really assigning values to variables with the syntax `$var="value"` are you? You want to use `var="value"` (note NO leading `$`). Maybe your are immitating the cmd line prompt with the leading `$`. If so, better to use `$[spaceChar]` as your prompt. Good luck.

Comment: Also, your LDAP query tool may have different output formats that are easier to parse (even if this one is not so bad), and you could probably filter-out un-needed records at the LDAP query level. Why pull data you don't need? Possibly you could get values only on their own line and not need to parse key names.

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n";q="Wireless MacAddress"}$0~q{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/uniq|Admin|User/||$i~q)print $i;print""}'`

Comment: @jhnc  Pleaese let me know if this is the correct usage of your "awk" 

cat Filename.txt | yourAWKstring >> Newfilename.txt

Comment: Yes, something like that. The regexes I gave can match incorrectly in some situations (eg. what if location field contains "Administration Building"?) but you can use the code as a starting point for a full solution. The key part is the bit that selects only the desired records: `awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" '/\nWireless MacAddress/{ ... }`